# Query en mongodb que busca restar dos campos y devolver los valores menores que

Tags: mongodb

tengo un collection en MongoDB con dos campos numéricos, que me gustaría hacer una query que reste estos dos campos y que devuelva los valores menores que un número, por ejemplo, algo como esto:

```
**db.getCollection("collection1").find({
field1 - field2 < 3
 })**
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si ambos campos son del mismo documento, puedes hacerlo con un aggregate.
Puedes agregar un campo con la diferencia y luego, en otra etapa, filtrar los que tengan el valor deseado